# Exit phonegap/go back to Android

Tags: android, cordova, exit-code

My question is a bit odd, but it really annoys me...

I have an Android app, and when you hit a button it loads

```
    loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html").
```

Everything fine by now. After I do my thing in web application I want to go back to my Android app from which I started my site.
To be more specific I want that when user hit a button in html page it closes that page and go back to:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setBooleanProperty("keepRunning", false);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Sorry for stupid question but i don't know how to form it any better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Cordova WebView which is release in v1.9.0 http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android

Answer (score 0):

This works in both Android and iOS:

```js
window.history.go( -( history.length - 1 ) );
```

But, the result are unpredictable once you get back. Sometimes PhoneGap is in a weird state and there is no way to refresh it.

After much headache and trying many things, I've come to the conclusion it's best to never leave the PhoneGap `UIWebView`. Instead, used the [ChildBrowser Plugin](https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser).